# SVG not rendered correctly with Qt

Tags: qt, svg, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to render [this SVG file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/58u25pqahqne3j7/test.svg?dl=1) using these lines:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtSvg

qApp = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
view = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(scene)
svg = QtSvg.QGraphicsSvgItem('test.svg')
scene.addItem(svg)
view.show()

qApp.exec_()
```

Unfortunately, the result looks like this:
[image]
instead of:
[image]
(actual image is much longer on the x-axis, this is just a section)

The ratio is way off and all defined symbols are not rendered at all. Any ideas on that?

Comment: I see lots of svg errors (all like "link E0A3 hasn't been detected!") when loading the file you linked to. I tried a few other large music score svg files and they all render perfectly fine, with no errors.

Comment: Hmm, the file is automatically generated by "verovio", so I should check back with the developer... I wonder why all browser render it correctly.